# how to close websocket server then restart in python

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to assign the websockets service based on the different options selected.
However, when I try to shut down websockets, it says there is no shutdown method.
Because they go on the same port the service is local, so I have to shut it down in order to start a websocketSever

```
Class WebSocketApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_account = None
        self.websocket_service = WebSocketSericeFactory()
        self.websocket_server = None
        
    def get_websocket_service(self, account):
        """Retrieve the appropriate WebSocket service for a given account."""
        return self.websocket_service.get_websocket_service(account)

    def start_websocket(self):
        """Start the WebSocket service."""
        if self.websocket_server is None:
            # Terminate any existing process on port 9991
            kill_process_on_port(9991)

            # Create a new SSL context for secure WebSocket communication
            ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
            ssl_context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
            
            # Create and start a new thread to run the WebSocket service
            self.websocket_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._run_websocket, args=(ssl_context,))
            self.websocket_thread.start()

    def stop_websocket(self):
        """Stop the WebSocket service."""
        if self.websocket_server is not None:
            # Terminate the WebSocket service
            self.websocket_server.close()
            
            # Stop the associated asyncio event loop
            asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()

            # Wait for the WebSocket thread to complete
            self.websocket_thread.join()
            self.websocket_server = None

    def _run_websocket(self, ssl_context):
        """Internal method to set up and run the WebSocket server."""
        # Create a new asyncio event loop for the WebSocket service
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        
        # Set up and start the WebSocket server
        self.websocket_server = websockets.serve(self.get_websocket_service(self.current_account), "localhost", 9991, ssl=ssl_context)
        loop.run_until_complete(self.websocket_server)
        
        # Keep the loop running indefinitely
        loop.run_forever()

    def switch_account(self, account):
        """Switch to a different account."""
        # First, stop the current WebSocket service
        self.stop_websocket()

        # Update the current account
        self.current_account = account

        # Then start a new WebSocket service for the new account
        self.start_websocket()
```

main.py

```
# Create Simple Image
def create_image():
    width, height = 64, 64
    color1 = "blue"
    color2 = "blue"
    image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), color1)
    dc = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    dc.rectangle(
        (width // 2, 0, width, height // 2),
        fill=color2)
    dc.rectangle(
        (0, height // 2, width // 2, height),
        fill=color2)

    return image
app = WebSocketApp()
icon = pystray.Icon("name", create_image(), "WebSocket Service", menu=pystray.Menu(
    Item('option1', lambda icon, item: app.switch_account(0)),
    Item('option2', lambda icon, item: app.switch_account(1)),
    pystray.MenuItem('Exit', lambda icon, item: icon.stop())
))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    icon.run()
```

When I press Option1, the service is started normally, but when I press Option2, he prompts me with the following message

> **AttributeError: 'Serve' object has no attribute 'close'**

How do I shut down websockets and restart the service?